# How to correct SecureCRT vbs Regex

Tags: regex, vbscript, secure-crt

So I made a vbs script for SecureCRT but it is not working.
The script should look inside a text and check all interfaces then loop through them by issuing a command for each interface.
the error I receive is in code line (Set matches = re.Execute(allthetext)) it is saying (Unexpected quantifier).

I hope to find a solotion

```
$language = "VBScript"
$interface = "1.0"

crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

Sub Main ()

    allthetext = "ge-10/1/2 but not ae22 and as well ge-1/0/0 in addtion xe-0/0/0:2, lets see"
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "\b{2}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}:\d|\b{2}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}"
    Set matches = re.Execute(allthetext)
    For Each match In matches
    theInterface = match.SubMatches(0)
    crt.Screen.Send "show interfaces " & theInterface & "| match ""down"" " & chr(13)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a regular expression problem, have added the tag to the question.

Comment: Yes I think it is a regex issue but not sure what is causing it. As for the main, no need need to call it as other scripts don't require it and they are working fine.

Comment: I corrected the regex now. It should be (re.pattern = "\w{2}-\d{1,3}\/\w{2}-\d{1,3}\/\w{2}-\d{1,3}" ) .... but I get the error (Invalid procedure call or argument) for the line (    theInterface = match.SubMatches(0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern does not work due to this part `\b{2}` where there is a quantifier for a word boundary that does not work.

You could either write the pattern as this, but note that there should be a word character before the starting `-`

```
\b-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}:\d|\b-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}
```

As there is some overlap in the pattern for the dash and digits part, you can rewrite it to this with an optional part for `:` and digit at the end using an optional group `(?::\d)?`

```
\b-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}(?::\d)?
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDRtZ1/1) for the matches.